# related to gdata in iphone

Tags: iphone

what are the settings needed to build gdata application in iphone

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) explains how to use the GData Objective-C Client library in an iOS application.